# ios game gets out of sync while analysing process in Instruments - how can I avoid that?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, instruments

I am building an iOS game and I notice that the game performs fine while running normally in the XCode debugger. However, when i run it from within Instruments (Product-> Profile to trace  Leaks), the game freezes when Instruments displays 'Analyzing Process' in the left sidebar. After that the game messes up all its state since some parts of the game that were being analyzed froze up while other parts kept going.

Is this something I can/need to fix or is it sufficient to make sure the game runs in release?

If a fix is needed, what do I need to do to make it work?

**Update 1:**

So we found the issue - the same problem repros even if we are playing the game, press the home button and click on the game icon and continue playing.

The issue is that most of our work is done in the update method, and it relies on the value of the (ccTime)dt parameter. The value of dt is usually < 0.1 seconds, and occasionally somewhere upto 0.5 seconds).When we pause (either by clicking the home button, or when instruments pauses the game to take a snapshot) and resume playing, the value of dt is several seconds! And that throws all our calculations out of range.

We tried a temporary (but ugly) workaround that fixes the issue: at the beginning of the update method, we add this:

```
if(dt > 1)
  return;
```

And it now works as expected - doesn't go out of sync. However, this is not a permanent solution, since sometimes, the values of dt are legitimately close to 1 second, and in resource crunched situations, this may lead to stutter (or worse).

We also considered another (equally ugly) solution of storing the previous value of dt, and then check in the update method:

```
if(dt > 10 * prevDt)
{
  return;
}
```

We tried calling `unscheduleUpdate` in `AppDelegate.m`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and called `scheduleUpdate` in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method, but that approach did not work.

What is the best way to deal with updates with erratic time values due to external pauses?

Thanks
Anand

Comment: why don't you just put the game in a paused state when you detect that the game was suspended?  After resuming you just reset the timers so the delta will not be ridiculously high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about how cocos2D works, but if you've run out of options, I would simply clamp the delta time to an upper range. In whatever update methods used delta time, I would do the following.

```
double delta = (dt > 0.5) : (0.5) ? (dt);
```

Use `delta` instead of `dt` from that point onward. The result is that any frame with a delta of over half a second will be limited to a delta of half a second. You don't want to skip frames, because then you could potentially skip many frames in a row which would be bad for the user; they'd probably think the app crashed or something. However, you don't want to run a frame with a large delta because then delta-dependent objects and forces will get multiplied many times for that frame, preventing you from catching collisions and stuff. So, we prevent the game from getting completely screwed over while not skipping frames by simply clamping the value downwards.

The negative is that the app will appear to move more slowly when your frame rate drops to 2 frames per second. You lose the benefit of a time-based update method, which is the ability to always make the game appear to run at a well defined speed, when the engine is overburdened.

To be honest, if you ever run at 2 frames per second for an extended period of time, you've got bigger problems to worry about. I don't think the user will notice if objects move slightly more slowly per second if the game is only rendering once every who-knows-when anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a problem, for which there is no sure answer; at least not without access to your system to run a whole variety of checks.

The failure in the profile may be because your game is running tight loops the timing of which get's upset in unpredictable ways and your game is crashing due to timing or resource issues (where those timing issues don't crop up with the debugger in the same way). If that's the case, there is probably not much you can do about it. Or it may be because there is a problem in your code. The problem is it can be very difficult to figure out which of these is the case. It's probably best to assume the problem is in your code though and do some further investigation.

The first thing to do, if you haven't done it already, is run the static analysis tool (Analyse from the Product menu in Xcode). Consider each of the raised errors carefully, and work to remove all of them. Sometimes they might seem obvious and you think you can ignore them, but some prodding reveals they are a symptom of a deeper problem.

If you haven't tried already, try running the instrument to check for zombies. There's a high chance this will fail also if the allocation instrument is failing, but if there are some stale references to de-allocated objects hanging around they could be causing the problem you are experiencing. Another instrument you can try is the performance analyser, to check where your app is spending most of it's time. There may be some really significant problem with the overallocation of resources you are not aware of. If you can't run the memory profiler, it will be difficult for you to see if this is the case, but using the performance analyser, it might be possible to see if your app is getting hung up for too long somewhere it shouldn't be.

Lastly - if all else fails and this may be a sledgehammer to crack a nut - and also may not in any case provide the solution. If you aren't using ARC, consider how long it would take to convert your app to using it (definitely create a branch first before doing it though). The Apple algorithms for object allocation/deallocation are very efficient and there is a very good chance if you have subtle memory management errors, they will be eliminated by Automatic Reference Counting.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - will try out your suggestions.

Comment: I tried some of your suggestions, but not much luck so far - my app runs fine when run outside of the leak instrument. I have also verified (by using different snapshots in instruments) that each part of my app runs without leaks. The only time there is a problem is when the app is analyzing the process while running from within the leak instrument. I want to decide how much I must invest in fixing this before submission - is this a certain/likely cause for rejection or worth submitting anyway?